# Drawing a rotating/falling line in python

Tags: python

Hello I need to make an animation of a rotating line using the function :

```
def animation():
    line = create_line(startingpoint, endpoint, color, thickness)
    draw_line(line)
```

The starting point remains unchanged throughout the animation, only the endpoint has to rotate by 2°.

I already have a formula to draw and rotate a new line every 2°, the problem is that all my lines remain displayed through the multiple executions of the function and I only need the latest line to show.

I have tried drawing a second blank line to erase the first one but I have a nasty trail showing at some point.

Comment: What framework are you using for the drawing?

Comment: We are using VPL for moodle since it's a project we have to do as a part of our University program